# SQL Query in SQL Query PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to make an listview for my website. I tried to make this so I have more overview then only a long list with all the data.

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) { } 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Home_Rooms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "
<div class=\"container\"><hr></div>
<div class=\"container-fluid\">
  <div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"col-sm-1\">
    </div>
    <div class=\"col-sm-10\">
      <div class=\"panel-group\" id=\"accordion\">";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $room = $row["name"];
        echo "
        <div class=\"panel panel-info\">
          <div class=\"panel-heading\">
            <h4 class=\"panel-title\"><a data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapse" .$row["id"]."\">" .$row["name"]."</a></h4>
          </div>
          <div id=\"collapse" .$row["id"]."\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse\">
          <div class=\"panel-body\">";

$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) { } 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Home_Devices WHERE room='$room'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row_room = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
      <div class=\"media\">
        <div class=\"media-left\">
          <img src=\"/image/pictures/" .$row_room["type"].".png\" class=\"media-object\" style=\"width:60px\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"media-body\">
          <h4 class=\"media-heading\"><a href=\"/dashboard/" .$row_room["sensor_id"]."\">" .$row_room["room"]." - " .$row_room["name"]."</a></h4>
          <p>Sensor ID: " .$row_room["sensor_id"]."</p>
        </div>
      </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No devices found, you can add devices <a href=\"/settings\">here</a>.</p>";
}

      echo"</div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    }

    echo "
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>";

} else {
    echo "<p>No rooms found, you can add rooms <a href=\"/settings\">here</a>.</p>";
}
$conn->close();
```

But this didn't load all the rooms, only the first room. Could someone help me fix this? Is this even possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong.. For starters, you are using the $result 2 times..

Comment: @Naruto So I have to make alle the arrays different?

Comment: @Vítek No, because then i would get an error loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to define $conn inside your while statement. It's already defined at the start of the code.
Also, why are you using the same variable $result for the room data, same as your Home_Rooms?
Try using a different variable the second time around, cause it's probably screwing up your while statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your Result variable is Overwrite

Change that variable.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Home_Devices WHERE room='$room'";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
```

and change respective variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have it working,

I had to change all the arrays different.

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) { } 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Home_Rooms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "
<div class=\"container\"><hr></div>
<div class=\"container-fluid\">
  <div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"col-sm-1\">
    </div>
    <div class=\"col-sm-10\">
      <div class=\"panel-group\" id=\"accordion\">";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $room = $row["name"];
        echo "
        <div class=\"panel panel-info\">
          <div class=\"panel-heading\">
            <h4 class=\"panel-title\"><a data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapse" .$row["id"]."\">" .$row["name"]."</a></h4>
          </div>
          <div id=\"collapse" .$row["id"]."\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse\">
          <div class=\"panel-body\">";

$conn_2 = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
if ($conn_2->connect_error) { } 

$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM Home_Devices WHERE room='$room'";
$result_2 = $conn_2->query($sql_2);

if ($result_2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row_room = $result_2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
      <div class=\"media\">
        <div class=\"media-left\">
          <img src=\"/image/pictures/" .$row_room["type"].".png\" class=\"media-object\" style=\"width:60px\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"media-body\">
          <h4 class=\"media-heading\"><a href=\"/dashboard/" .$row_room["sensor_id"]."\">" .$row_room["room"]." - " .$row_room["name"]."</a></h4>
          <p>Sensor ID: " .$row_room["sensor_id"]."</p>
        </div>
      </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No devices found, you can add devices <a href=\"/settings\">here</a>.</p>";
}

      echo"</div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    }

    echo "
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>";

} else {
    echo "<p>No rooms found, you can add rooms <a href=\"/settings\">here</a>.</p>";
}
$conn->close();
```